# How can I call javascript library functions externally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I'm working on an app that deals with web audio and waveform display.

For it, I'm using a library called [Wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) made for specifically that.

The problem I'm running into is calling the function for the track to play. I tried putting it into a external JavaScript script using jQuery's .click(), but it didn't work.

So, I decided to try the onclick() event on the button itself like this:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
    Play
  </button>
</div>
```

and the only change is that it tells me in the console, "wavesurfer is not defined.", but it HAS to be defined since it's still drawing the waveform of the audio!

The strangest part is this EXACT code works fine in [CodePen!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjmYRP)

EDIT: Full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.1.2/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\wavesurfer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="waveform"></div>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
Play
  </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'red',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});
wavesurfer.load('https://archive.org/download/Metallica_37/Metallica-MasterOfPuppets.mp3');

});
```

Comment: only thing I can suggest is that the order of loading the wavesurfer js and your code is not exactly correct - on codepen there are three tabs, for HTML, CSS and JS - but you haven't shown how your non-working code is ordered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variable Scope

The problem you are having is one of scope.

**What is Scope**

All variables in javascript have a scope. A variable can not be access if it is out of scope. For variables declared with the `var` token their scope is to the function they are declared in. Variables declared outside any function has a global scope. Global scope means that the variable can be access from anywhere on the page.

Example

```
var myGlobal = 10; // this is outside any function and is global
function myFunction(){
    var myFuncLoc = 20;  // this is inside the function and scoped to the function
    console.log(myFuncLoc); // >> 20  // is in scope can be displayed
    console.log(myGlobal); // >> 10  // is in scope can be displayed
    function(){
        var myFuncLoc1 = 30;
        console.log(myFuncLoc); // >> 20  // is in scope can be displayed
        console.log(myFuncLoc1); // >> 30  // is in scope can be displayed
        console.log(myGlobal); // >> 10  // is in scope can be displayed
    }
    console.log(myFuncLoc); // >> 20  // is in scope can be displayed
    console.log(myGlobal); // >> 10  // is in scope can be displayed
    // next is out of scope
    console.log(myFuncLoc1); // Throws ReferenceError: myFuncLoc1 is not defined
}
console.log(myGlobal); // >> 10  // is in scope can be displayed
    // next is out of scope
console.log(myFuncLoc); // Throws ReferenceError: myFuncLoc is not defined
console.log(myFuncLoc1); // Throws ReferenceError: myFuncLoc1 is not defined
```

That is a brief overview and there is also the block scoped variable declarations with the tokens `let` and `const` A block is everything inside `{` `}` You should read up on scope as that is an important concept for almost all programing languages.

**What is wrong**

So your problem is you have a variable that is out of scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // wavesurfer is scoped to this function only
    // and can not be seen in the global scope.
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: 'red',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    });
    wavesurfer.load('https://archive.org/download/Metallica_37/Metallica-MasterOfPuppets.mp3');

});
```

The onclick is in the global scope and can not see the variable that has been declared in function scope.

```
<!-- can not see wavesurfer -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
```

**The hack fix.**

To fix you can ensure wavesurfer is global

```
// outside any function
var wavesurfer; // declares wavesurfer as a globally scoped variable

$(document).ready(function(){
    // wavesurfer is global
    // so do not use the var token be cause if you do then you create a second
    // variable called wavesurfer inside this function
    wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({  
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: 'red',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    });
    wavesurfer.load('https://archive.org/download/Metallica_37/Metallica-MasterOfPuppets.mp3');

});
```

That will fix your problem

**The prefered fix**

A better solution is to add the onclick event where the wavesurfer has scope and this avoids polluting the global scope.

Change the button

```
<!-- remove the onclick from the play button and give it an id-->
<button class="btn btn-primary" id='playButton'>
```

And then the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // function scope wavesurfer
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({  
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: 'red',
        progressColor: 'purple'
    });

    wavesurfer.load('https://archive.org/download/Metallica_37/Metallica-MasterOfPuppets.mp3');

    // use only one of the following code lines

    // add the click event where wavesurfer has scope.
    playButton.addEventListener("click",function(){wavesurfer.playPause()});

    // for the purists :P
    document.getElementById("playButton").addEventListener("click", function(){wavesurfer.playPause()});

});
```

Comment: Simple, straight forward, multiple working solutions. couldn't ask for a better response! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to import Waveform AJAX library & Bootstrap in the head as

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.1.2/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and then a wavesurfer object as

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    waveColor: 'grey',
    progressColor: '#ff7700',
});

// Song Goes Here!
wavesurfer.load('https://archive.org/download/Metallica_37/Metallica-MasterOfPuppets.mp3');
```

and then you code can look like

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">
    Play
  </button>
</div>
```

which plays the song `Metallica - Master of Puppets`

Comment: Why does it need to be in the `head`? Scripts in `head` (without `async` or `defer`) is an anti-pattern, and has been well-known as such for a decade or so: https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: its a common practice, i have many people add script at the end, but i have no idea why, maybe because i am a noob in web prog myself, soz for any misunderstanding, correct me and i'll edit my post @T.J.Crowder

Comment: See the link for why.

Comment: we have to say, "METAALLLLL"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new [codePen](http://codepen.io/kermani/pen/ZpbRxr)

What was the problem?

You needed to add the wavesurfer.js source (from CDN) to codePen:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.0.52/wavesurfer.min.js
```

[image]

**How does wavesuffer.js works step by step?** *(from [documentation](https://wavesurfer-js.org/))*

1-Create a container:

```
<div id="waveform"></div>
```

2-create a wavesurfer instance:

```
var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
container: '#waveform',
waveColor: 'violet',
progressColor: 'purple'
});
```

3-load the audio:

```
 wavesurfer.load('audio.wav');
```